# Are forces from different directions applied to a hanging mass the same?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's assume a mass that is hanging somewhere. My question is basically:

1. We are applying a force from the side to move the mass sidewards
2. We are applying a force from below to move the mass upwards

Are these forces the same?

In this context, a bit more concise and realistic:
A box, weighing 100 kg, is hanging from a crane. An architect wants to figure out which way it is easier to move that weight.

Comment: This needs some clarification. Are you asking whether the force to accelerate the box sideways is as large in magnitude ("as strong") as a force moving it upwards with the same acceleration?

Comment: I'm more interested in the force I have to apply but I think I just repeat myself now :) 
But this is probably the connected side question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the mass $m$ is a scalar quantity and when you describe Newton's 2nd law in vector form you have

$$ \vec{F} = m\, \vec{a}$$

$$ \pmatrix{F_x \\ F_y} = m \pmatrix{a_x \\ a_y} = \pmatrix{m\, a_x \\ m\, a_y} $$

So if the resulting acceleration is to be the same in both directions ($a_x = a_y$) then the forces applied are the same ($F_x = F_y$)

**<sub>The above is in theory only, as it ignores gravity.</sub>**

With gravity, and with $F_x$ and $F_y$ defined as the **applied forces** on the body, you have $$ \pmatrix{F_x \\ F_y} + \pmatrix{0 \\ -m g} =  \pmatrix{m\,a_x \\ m\,a_y} $$

Remember Newton's 2nd law involves the *sum* of forces applied to a body. In this case, I am adding the weight (pointing downwards).

So the applied force to achieve acceleration is different by the weight of the body

$$ F_x = m (a_x) $$
$$ F_y = m ( a_y + g) $$

Comment: so I don't consider the gravitational force which is in case working against me and in the other it isn't?

Comment: Thanks, but what is the statement actually? I'd conclude that now the forces are differently?

Comment: Ok, someone downvoted you (it wasn't me!)..  just recognized, doesn't matter but why are people doing that..

Comment: @Ben - no worries. See my update now. As to why people downvote, I wouldn't try to guess unless they add a comment about it.